# Select the row with minimum value in a table that has duplicate data

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have an AWS Athena (presto) table that has some rows that are duplicate except for one column, modifydate:

```
"feeder","circuitid","pole","phase","starttime","endtime","modifydate","eventduration"
"SOUTH","27802","1860981454636","C","2020-09-16 03:43:00.000","2020-09-16 03:49:00.000","2020-09-23 11:00:00.000","6"
"SOUTH","27802","1860981454636","C","2020-09-16 03:43:00.000","2020-09-16 03:49:00.000","2020-09-16 03:49:00.000","6"
```

I need to select a set of records from this table with a select clause based on starttime, and where there are rows that are duplicated (less than 2% of the table), only select the row with the smallest (oldest) modifydate. In the above example, the second row should be returned.

Here's what I've done:

```
SELECT p.* FROM event_frames as p where 
starttime between date '2020-09-16' and date '2020-09-17' and
modifydate = 
(select MIN(p2.modifydate) from event_frames as p2 where 
 p.feeder = p2.feeder and
 p.phase = p2.phase and
 p.circuitid = p2.circuitid  and 
 p.polenumbers = p2.polenumbers and
 p.starttime = p2.starttime and
 p.endtime = p2.endtime and
p.eventduration = p2.eventduration)
```

And this works, but ONLY for rows that are duplicated according to my description above. I need to return both single rows AND one duplicate row with MIN(modifydate)

Is that possible?

Comment: I guess you're already familiar with [`min_by()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#min_by)?

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I'm not, but would that help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select feeder, phase, circuitid, polenumbers, starttime, endtime, eventduration,
       min(modifydate) as modifydate
from event_frames
group by feeder, phase, circuitid, polenumbers, starttime, endtime, eventduration;
```